# Given a set of data, check if it is a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

The detailed description of this problem is as follows:
each row contains two values `x` and `y`, which denotes that the node with key `x` is the parent of the node with key `y`. The first `y` is the left child of `x`, the second `y` is the right child of `x`. If the `y` is `-1`, there is no corresponding child of `x` . Notice that the keys of all the nodes in the tree are **distinct** and **positive**.

**Added**: I've already found some mistakes in my code: **1.** The nodes given in the data set may not be from the first layer to the bottom layer, which means after read one line, I need to search the index of the parent node and then add the child. **2**. The `isBST()` function is not correct since a tree is a binary search tree if the **left subtree** is recursively smaller than the current node and the **right subtree** is recursively larger than the current node. *The first one is easy to solve but I have no idea how to solve the second one.*

Sample Input

```
4
10 5
10 30
30 20
30 -1
```

the number on the first row denotes the number of rows below.
for each row, the left number denotes the parent, and the right number denotes the child. If the right number is `-1`, it means that there is no corresponding child.

Sample Output

```
YES 2
```

I think my code can successfully pass the test points when the answer should be "No". However, for those cases that should be "YES + num", my code fails. Could anybody point out the mistakes in my code?

Actually, I am not quite sure about the accurate definition of Binary search tree. For the sample input, I do not think it is a complete binary tree. Do I need to take the number of layers of this tree into consideration?

My idea is quite straightforward, I just read the data and store them into an array and use the property that the left child for a value stored at index `i` is `2 * i` and the right child is `2 * i + 1`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BST {

    public static int[] readData() throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // get the number of rows
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] strs;
        int[] res = new int[2 * n];
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            strs = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
            
            // read the left and right number of one row resp.
            int parent = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
            int child = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
            // which means that there is no corresponding child, use 0 to denote null
            if (child == -1) {
                child = 0;
            }
            // read the second line with the same parent
            if (res[i - 1] == parent) {
            // put the child as the right child 
                res[2 * (i - 1) + 1] = child;
            }
            else {
                res[i] = parent;
                res[2 * i] = child;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return res;
    }
    
    public static boolean isLeaf(int[] data, int index) {
        
        // if the node is null, it is not a leaf
        if (data[index] == 0) return false;
        
        
        if (2 * index < data.length - 1) {
            // the left and right children are both null
            if (data[2 * index] == 0 && data[2 * index + 1] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            // the left and right children are not both null
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // 2 * index is out of bound
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public static int countLeaf(int[] data) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            // if the node is a leaf, count it
            if (isLeaf(data, i)) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    public static boolean checkBSTprop(int[] data, int index) {
        // no child can be found
        if (2 * index >= data.length) {
            return true;
        }
        // no child
        if (data[2 * index] == 0 && data[2 * index + 1] == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        // left child is 0, right child is nonzero
        if (data[2 * index] == 0 && data[2 * index + 1] > data[index]) {
            return true;
        }
        // right child is 0, left child is nonzero
        if (data[2 * index + 1] == 0 && data[2 * index] < data[index]) {
            return true;
        }
        // both children are nonzero
        if (data[2 * index] < data[index] && data[2 * index + 1] > data[index]) {
            return true;
        }
        // none of the conditions are satisfied
        return false;
    }
    
    public static boolean isBST(int[] data) {
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (!checkBSTprop(data, i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] res = readData();
        int num = countLeaf(res);
        
        /*
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
        System.out.println(countLeaf(res));
        System.out.println(checkBSTprop(res, 1));
        System.out.println(checkBSTprop(res, 2));
        System.out.println(checkBSTprop(res, 3));
        System.out.println(checkBSTprop(res, 6));
        System.out.println(isBST(res));
        */
        
        if (isBST(res)) {
            System.out.println("YES " + num);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: BST actually means "Binary Search Tree"

Comment: The input format gives no clue about left and right. At least there is a specification missing. Possibly there is a rule that the first mentioned child is always assumed to be a left child, and the second is a right child, and that for each node it is guaranteed that both left and right child will be mentioned in the input, and in that order. This should be clarified. Why for instance does the input not have "5 -1" and "5 -1"? Is there an assumption that if a node is a leaf, it is never listed like that?

Comment: @trincot I just added the detailed description of this problem. I think the problem assumes that if the node is a left child, then there will not be statement like `5 -1`.

Comment: What does the number in the expected output indicate (e.g. `YES 2`)?  Number of nodes?  Depth of tree?  Is there a consistent order to the input?  Does the BST allow duplicates?

Comment: @vsfDawg The number 2 means the number of leaf nodes. There is no duplicate nodes and also all the values of nodes are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will not work consistently, because:

- A binary search tree does not have to be a complete tree
- It is not guaranteed that the order of the input will be breadth-first
- It seems not guaranteed that the two children of the same parent, appear right after each other in the input.

For this reason you cannot use `i` to define where in the array to store a node's value, with a formula like `2 * (i - 1) + 1`, nor can you check that the parent already has appeared before with `res[i - 1]`.

For instance, your program will answer "NO" for this valid BST:

```
6
3 2
3 -1
2 1
2 -1
1 -1
1 -1
```

And if we input the same tree, without the unnecessary `1 -1` (twice), like this:

```
4
3 2
3 -1
2 1
2 -1
```

...then there is an out-of-bounds exception.

Secondly, it is not enough in `isBST` to compare the value of a child with its parent. Even when that comparison is fine, you could still have an invalid BST, like for example this one:

```
                  4
                /
               1
                 \
                  10
```

This is invalid, as the only valid (distinct) integer values for that leaf are 2 or 3. So you need to have to check against a range that sifts down the recursion tree.

A pragmatic solution is to really build the tree with `Node` class instances, and let `isBST` be an instance method of that class, which takes into account also this range requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I took your advice and used the `Node` class method. With some effort, I finally worked out and my code passed the OJ system test. Thank you very much!